# How to give a permission to only some users with same role in drupal?

Tags: php, drupal-6

If I have 3 users of same role (program manager) and now I have to give some permissions(add/edit/delete) to only 1 user in it. Can I do this instead of assigning to a particular role so that every user containing the role gets the permissions?

Answer (score 2):

Just add a role containing ONLY the special permissions and then assign that new role AND the program manager role to the person(s) you want (users can have more then 1 role in Drupal). You don't need any 3rd party lib for that functionality.

Comment: Some people don't accept any form of (constructive) criticism I guess.

Comment: Did not know that. Use his answer.

Answer (score 0):

The point of roles is to allocate permissions to blocks or types of users.  These roles do not necessarily have to correspond to an individual's role within an organization.  For example, you could make the one with special permissions an Editing Program Manager, which would be a new role you create with all of the same permissions, plus those extras that the specific user needs.

Comment: Thank u so much for responding .... can i get any contributed module in drupal for the question..??? plz can u get me...